# prestashop add images to products

Tags: php, prestashop

I have a product object, which I am creating in a PHP script. I need to add a thumbnail and a large image, which I have in a zip file. The file name contains the product ID.

Whats the best way to achieve this in code? I'm assuming I need to extract the images to somewhere in file system, but I have no idea how prestashop handles images.

thanks!

Comment: try logging into the admin interface, it's got everything.

Comment: I am not able to provide you with exact route, however, go and look in  classes and controllers, to get a grip, how it is done by prestashop. I would recommend looking in `controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php`. I know, that those 5000 lines of code is too much, albeit try :-D. Then take look into image classes, since they are only way, where image processing interface is created. classes/Image.php and classes/ImageManager.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have the Product ID ($id_product) and the image URL ($url), you can do the following:

```
$image = new Image();
$image->id_product = $id_product;
$image->position = Image::getHighestPosition($id_product) + 1;
$image->cover = true; // or false;
if (($image->validateFields(false, true)) === true &&
($image->validateFieldsLang(false, true)) === true && $image->add())
{
    $image->associateTo($shops);
    if (!self::copyImg($id_product, $image->id, $url, 'products', false))
    {
        $image->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks exactly like what i need, however I'm getting a php error when I try running this. "cannot access self:: when no class scope is active".

Comment: You can copy the method "copyImg" from controllers/admin/AdminImportController.php in your class (as a method), or script (as a function)

If you copy it as a function just remove "protected static" and remove the "self::" when calling it.

Comment: My 2 cents, I have noticed that passing the last parameter of the copyImg to "true" is far more...mh... safe, because PS will regenerate the image, I've used this code and it works only if that parameter is "true"

Comment: How to use this piece of code within a loop if i have multiple images for 1 product.

Comment: @Matteo Bononi 'peorthyr' Regenerating the images during the initial upload is not recommended, if you have many images, since it may cause script timeout. This is a time consuming operation.

Comment: This code adds product images also in the admin section? Because when I try this code there aren't any images.

Comment: @Shadow_X The last parameter of method copyImg() is false, which means the images for the product are not regenerated. If you pass true, all thumbs will be regenerated for that product and they will appear at the BackOffice.

Comment: @PrestaShopDeveloper thanks for your reply. I changed the last paramter to true, but still no images